# Update formArray without valueChanges emiting

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Have form like this:

```
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, [Validators.required]],
      companyHolderUid: [null],
      generalDescription: [null],
      authority: [TemplateAuthorities.Root],
      tabs: this.fb.array([]),
      tagReferences: this.fb.array([]),
    }, { updateOn: 'blur' });
```

I want to update *tabs* or *tagReferences* without triggering valueChanges. Something like this
`{ emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true }`

When using patchValue and trying to console *tabs* is empty

```
  private formInit(template: AssetTemplate) {
    this.form.patchValue({
      name: template.name,
      companyHolderUid: template.companyHolderUid,
      generalDescription: template.generalDescription,
      authority: template.authority,
      tabs: [1,2,3,4]
    }, { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.form.value));

  }
```

console.log result:

```
{
   "name":"test template",
  "companyHolderUid":null,
  "generalDescription":"Lorem ipsum",
  "authority":"ROOT",
  "tabs":[],
  "tagReferences":[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) method.
You can pass the whole form value, or update specific fields only if you will.

```
const newValue = [];
this.form.patchValue({ tabs: newValue }, { emitEvent: false });
```

Comment: Use something like this, but when trying to console - *tabs* is empty

```
  private formInit(template: AssetTemplate) {
    this.form.patchValue({
      name: template.name,
      companyHolderUid: template.companyHolderUid,
      generalDescription: template.generalDescription,
      authority: template.authority,
      tabs: [1,2,3,4]
    }, { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true });
    // this.form.setControl('tagReferences', this.fb.array(this.template.tagReferences || []));
    // this.form.setControl('tabs', this.fb.array(this.template.tabs));
  }
```

Comment: Can you update your question and post your whole code ?

Comment: I meant, litteraly your whole code, including the `console.log`.